# Can't set CALayer frame

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, calayer, subview

I am trying to set the frame of my `CALayer` in this code below

```
CGRect VFrame;
VFrame = CGRectMake(self.viewNo2.frame.origin.x, self.viewNo2.frame.origin.y, self.viewNo2.frame.size.width, self.viewNo2.frame.size.height);

self.customLayer = [CALayer layer];
self.customLayer.frame = VFrame;
self.customLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.customLayer];
```

For some reason the layer goes somewhere around this frame but not as the frame I am trying to declare.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Do you have any transforms applied or anything? Also I often find it easier to use `bounds` and `position` when dealing with `CALayers`.

Comment: What do you mean by "...ayer goes somewhere around this frame but not as the frame I am trying to declare" ?

Comment: Have you found any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this,simply assign frame to viewNo2 frame
self.viewNo2.frame.size.width, self.viewNo2.frame.size.height);
self.customLayer = [CALayer layer];
self.customLayer.frame = viewNo2.frame;
self.customLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.customLayer];
```